# A curious case of Print in VB6

Tags: vb6, stream, ms-word

I have this code in `VisualBasic 6`:

```
iLinha = FreeFile
Open strPath For Output As #iLinha
Dim strHeader As String

'***Assign a value to the string `Content`  

Print #iLinha, strHeader
```

Now I'm trying to do the same of this code **but** using the `Word.Application`, you know ?
And When I code this:

```
Word.Selection.TypeText strHeader
```

All I got is just codes and characters like: `{rtf1\ansi\ansipg1252\deff0....`

Could anyone explain to me that code above ? The  Print `#iLinha`

**Update**

```
streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
streamFile.Open
streamFile.Write rstAux.Fields("text")
streamFile.SaveToFile strCaminhoTemp, adSaveCreateOverWrite
streamFile.Close
```

Obs: I tried change the `adTypeBinary` to `adTypeText` but several errors ocurred...

maybe this code has something to do with my problem ?!!

Comment: Your new update still does not explain how you get data for `strHeader`

Comment: @George it's from a database table. It's a `LongBloob` type. When using the `SreamFile` it creates a temporary file with a model of the letter with 1 image and some text... I tried to use `Word_App.Selection.TypeText variable`, to write the same thing of the temporary field in the `MS Word`. But All I got in the Word is just chinese characters... D:

Comment: @George It's working fine when opening with `WordPad` but when I try to open it wit h`MS Word` the identation is a little messed up.

Comment: So word opens fine with no codes and weird characters? The issue now is the indentation only? Please confirm

Comment: @George Yes, it opens clean code. Just the indentation in some places and it vary according to the resolution of the monitor aswell.

Comment: I think you may have the issue of a font that is not a `fixed-width` font. See if you can set your Word object to a fixed-width font like `Lucida Console`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `strHeader` is a formatted text, not a pure text.

Looks like `strHeader` at some point gets its value from an RTF (RichText) control and it gets a formatted text, not pure text.

more info on the RTF control: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234980%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why my post didn't get sent a while ago.  Anyway, as George pointed out, it's just RTF text.  My suggestion is that you apply the text to an RTF control and retrieve it back as plain text.  That will remove all the RTF code and leave you with the plain text that you so desire.

To do this, while your project is open in VB6, press Ctrl+T, and check "Microsoft Rich TextBox Control". You can add this new control to your form, but make it invisible. Then set the `RTFText` property to your `strHeader`, and grab the rich edit control's `Text` property.

Comment: Keep it as `adTypeBinary`.  The RTF code is fine.  You just need to parse it out.

Comment: I can't create a `RichTextBox` to do as you suggested. Is there another way to convert this `RTF` to pure text ? Then I could create a `doc` file using the `Word.Application` and `Word.Document`.

Comment: Oh, you could just save the text to an `rtf` file.  It'll open up just fine in as a Word document :).

Comment: I'm already doing this.... It's opening just fine in the `WordPad` but when I try to open it with `MS Word` the identation is a little messed up you know ?

Comment: I've posted an answer that will help with converting your RTF to text manually, which I don't recommend.  I really recommend you take my original suggestion of using the RichTextBox control provided by Microsoft and have it handle the conversion for you.

Comment: am I able to create a `RichTextBox` via code ? Or just by `Drag&Drop` the component ? I tried something and I found just `RichTextLib`.

Comment: I added instructions to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'd prefer something like [THIS](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/VBasic/116872/116872/creating-a-rich-text-box-at-runtime/). Is that possible ? To create it at runtime? I just didn't understand exactly the code from the link.

Comment: Creating controls that way can be dangerous.  Also, that still requires you to add a reference/component.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from the RTF format to Text format, you can write something like this manually, if you are not interested in using the RTF control, as you indicated - which I don't recommend:

```
Dim RTF As String
RTF = strHeader

Dim Text As String
Dim X As Long
Dim InTag As Boolean
Dim TagStarted As Boolean
For X = 1& To Len(RTF)
    Select Case Mid$(RTF, X, 1&)
    Case "{", "}"
        If InTag And Not TagStarted Then
            Text = Text & Mid$(RTF, X, 1&)
            TagStarted = True
        End If
    Case "\"
        If InTag And Not TagStarted Then
            Text = Text & Mid$(RTF, X, 1&)
            TagStarted = True
        Else
            InTag = True
            If Mid$(RTF, X, 5&) = "\par " Or Mid$(RTF, X, 4&) = "\par\" Or Mid$(RTF, X, 6&) = "\line " Or Mid$(RTF, X, 5&) = "\line\" Then
                Text = Text & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Case " "
        If InTag Then
            InTag = False
        Else
            Text = Text & " "
        End If
    Case Else
        If InTag Then
            TagStarted = True
        Else
            Text = Text & Mid$(RTF, X, 1&)
        End If
    End Select
Next X

MsgBox Text
```

Please note, that there is likely a few tweaks that may have to be made, as the code was quickly written.